# Is it possible to set font per mode/buffer and per charset in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'd like to set font according to the major mode and charset in Emacs, for example, when I open an org file, I expect to see that ASCII characters display with font "Consolas", and Chinese or Japanese characters display with font "Microsoft Yahei".

Currently I use a minor mode called `buffer-face-mode` and could make the font change corresponding to the major mode:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:font "Consolas-10.5"))
                           (buffer-face-mode)))
```

I viewed [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html) but seems there is no any charset attribute of a face that I can set or change, so I cannot continue to set font according to different charset.

And I know there is another function `set-fontset-font` could set font according to charset, but it can only be applied to frame, not buffer or mode.

So, is there a way to set different font to different charset with `buffer-face-mode`, or a workaround to get my original request implemented?

Thanks in advance,

Kelvin

Answer (score 0):

Here are some clues to search : until Emacs22 I used to define some personal fontsets, I am not sure that this is still a a valid way to do.

- create a new fontset that describes a mapping between a list of encodings and the fonts to render each of them
- use that font / fontset with the `default-frame-alist`, I don't know how to associate it only for a specific mode

```lisp
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
    "-*-consolas-*-*-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-fontset-consolas,
    ascii:-*-consolas-*-*-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1,
    latin-iso8859-1:-*-consolas-*-*-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1,
    latin-iso8859-15:-*-consolas-*-*-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-15")

(setq default-frame-alist '((width . 100) 
   (height . 44) 
   (top . 50) ;pixels
   (left . 50) ;pixels
   (font . "fontset-consolas")
   ))
```

Here I am always associating the same font for several encoding, but you can use different fonts.

Comment: First thank you for your answer, I tried this, but the font did not change, then I evaluated `(frame-parameter nil 'font)`, found that the fontset is still the default one (not "fontset-consolas").

Comment: And, assuming this could take effect, I think it will set all buffers to the fontset defined above, not only the buffers with major mode "org-mode", so is there a function could set only a buffer to a specific fontset, but not the frame?

Comment: @KelvinHu: yes, the definition of the `default-frame-alist` is done in my `.emacs` and has effect after for the first frame after startup and independantly of the mode. I am not fluent enough in elisp to tell how to make it effective at any time and for a specific mode. Sorry.

Comment: I tried and googled a lot, and find maybe this could not be done in usual way, what I can think out is defining an advice of `switch-to-buffer`, and change the font size/family there, but this will change the frame size also. So now I'd like to set font for all buffers, it is not perfect, but also acceptable. However, thanks for your answer.